# How to get the value of an html element using HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl

I have a perl array:

```
Print Dumper(\@jsession);

$VAR1 = [
'<html><body><form name = \'form\' id=\'form\' method = \'POST\' action = \'/Site.jsp\'><input type = hidden name = \'phpSessionID\' value = \'RBOpXs47l6AOw**\'><input type = hidden name = \'LoggedUserName\' value = \'User\'><!--input type = submit name = \'button\' value = \'goAhead\'--></form> <script language = \'JavaScript\'> document.getElementById(\'frmWelcome\').submit();</script></body'</html>
];
```

I want to get the value of the phpSessionID element into a perl variable.

Here is the HTML::TreeBuilder code that i tried:

```
$tree=HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(@jsession);
$tree->dump();
```

It actually prints the HTML part  from the array,But how do i use it to get the value of the element that i need?

Here is the code that actually worked for me,in case anyone else where to search for this:

```
$tree=HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(@jsession);
$first_match = $tree->find_by_attribute('name' => 'phpSessionID');
$first_match->dump();
$value = $first_match->attr('value');
chomp($value);
print "$value";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use look_down (https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#look_down) from the root element to describe and find the element you want -

```
@elements = $h->look_down( ...criteria... ); 
$first_match = $h->look_down( ...criteria... );
```

> This starts at `$h` and looks thru its
>   element descendants (in pre-order), looking for elements matching the
>   criteria you specify. In list context, returns all elements that match
>   all the given criteria; in scalar context, returns the first such
>   element (or undef, if nothing matched).

Then use attr (https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#attr) on the found element to get the attribute value.

```
$value = $h->attr('attr');
$old_value = $h->attr('attr', $new_value);
```

> Returns (optionally sets) the value of the given attribute of $h. The
>   attribute name (but not the value, if provided) is forced to
>   lowercase. If trying to read the value of an attribute not present for
>   this element, the return value is undef. If setting a new value, the
>   old value of that attribute is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nudging me in the right direction.I have updated my post with the solution also.

Comment: Note re: find_by_attribute: "This method is deprecated in favor of the more expressive look_down method, which new code should use instead." - `$tree->look_down( _tag => 'input', name => 'phpSessionID')`